# How to export multiple sheets from google spreadsheet to excel separately

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Do you know, or is it possible to create a script in google spreadsheet, that would download all sheets from this spreadsheet into excel separately? I Have a spreadsheet "Europe" with 25 sheets named let´s say Sheet1, Sheet2, ..., Sheet25 and I need to have 25 separate excel files named Sheet1, Sheet2 etc...

My idea is to go trough custom menu toolbar, with assigning some script that can "do this job". BUT I´m not an IT to create it by myself from scratch (custom menu script I´m familiar with already :) )

Could you help? Any tips/trics/ideas/already existing guidelines?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert your spreadsheet with 25 sheets into 25 different spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for this to work you download the google sheet file as an excel document inclusive of all the sheets. Then from there use VBA in order to separate all those sheets into separate files.

It would look something along the lines of this, but plug in the appropriate inputs where applicable. This will not break any links to your original workbook, so be mindful of that.

```
Sub NewWorkbooks()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Name As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In Workbooks("YourWorkbookHere"). _
Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"))
        ws.Copy
        Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
        With NewBook
            .SaveAs Filename:="PutFolderLocationHere" & " - " & ws.Name
            .Close 
        End With
Next

End Sub
```